# How osgi bundle undeployment works on jboss?

Tags: jboss, osgi, wildfly, osgi-bundle

I have two OSGI bundles(base, dependent), dependent bundle accessing some API of base bundle. When I undeploy base bundle and redeploy it I am getting **"Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.base-1.0.jar".main is already registered"**, however undeployment of base bundle was successful.

I want to understand how undeployment of osgi bundle works when there are couple of bundles dependent on it.

**Base Bundle Manifest**

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Bundle-Activator: com.learning.base.BaseBundleActivator

Bundle-Category: osgi

Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2

Bundle-Name: base

Bundle-SymbolicName: OSGI.base

Bundle-Version: 1.0.0

Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin

Export-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.7",com.learning.base.model;version="1.0.0",com.learning.base.service;version="1.0.0";uses:="com.learning.base.model"

Import-Package: com.learning.base.model;version="[1.0,2)",com.learning.base.service;version="[1.0,2)",javax.security.auth.x500,org.osgi.framework;version="[1.7,2)"

Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

Tool: Bnd-3.2.0.201605172007

**Dependent Bundle Manifest**

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Bundle-Activator: com.learning.dependent.DependentBundleActivator

Bundle-Category: osgi

Bundle-Name: dependent

Bundle-SymbolicName: OSGI.dependent

Bundle-Version: 1.0.0

Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin

Export-Package: com.learning.dependent.model;version="1.0.0";uses:="com.learning.base.model",com.learning.dependent.service;version="1.0.0";uses:="com.learning.dependent.model,org.osgi.framework"

Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="[1.7,2)",com.learning.base.model;version="[1.0,2)",com.learning.base.service;version="[1.0,2)"

Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

Tool: Bnd-3.2.0.201605172007